# How can I automate my user flow using Google Drive + Typeform + Mailchimp

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail, mailchimp, mailgun, zapier

I am trying to automate the user sign up and upload flow of our video editing service.

The current user flow is: 
1) User signs up on our website (www.gogramapp.com) using a typeform form.

2) Zapier takes the user email and name from typeform and creates a folder in our google drive with title: [Email, First Name, Last Name]

3) I then want to send the user an email with a link to their google drive folder that has been created. The user uploads their raw video files to that folder. We edit the files and send them back a professionally edited video.

Any ideas on how to get from step 2 to 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the directory using the [Google Drive](https://zapier.com/help/google-drive/) zap, then you just add another step that is the email after that? The link is an output from the Google Drive folder creation action.

Alternatively, Google Drive zap can trigger on a new folder created (it is a 'less common' option in the user interface) in a specific folder. You can then attach an email ([Gmail](https://zapier.com/help/gmail/) or whatever you are using) action to that.

Will that work for you?